# Tooltip working in localhost but not on a deployed site

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am using bootstrap tooltips in my site. When viewing it in localhost, the tooltip appears when hovered. However, when I view it on the deployed site, the tooltips do not work and I get the error "TypeError: f is not a function".

Here is my html:

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html=true title="ToolTipTitle" id="ToolTipID">2016</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({ 
        template: '<div class="tooltip"  id="CustomToolTips" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
   });
});
```

I do not understand what could be causing it to work in localhost but not on my deployed site. Is it the timing in which the tooltip is added?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused by the timing of the tooltip being created. I moved

```
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({ 
    template: '<div class="tooltip"  id="CustomToolTips" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
});
```

to the very end of the $(document).ready() and it fixed the issue